# when custom MessageBodyWriter and MessageBodyReader needs to written in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

My naive understanding (which could be totally wrong) is that whenever an incoming request stream needs to be translated to `POJO`, a custom `messageBodyReader` is necessary and for transmitting a `Java POJO` across the network as `Response`, a custom `messageBodyWriter`must be implemented.

Bu according the [jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) here (section 7.2.1), it says that

`Please note, that this is only a demonstration of how to write a custom entity provider. Jersey already contains default support for entity providers that can serialize JAXB beans into XML.`

I do not understand what this is supposed to mean? Does it mean there will be no need for implementing `messageReaders` if one uses `Jersey Framework`?

can someone kindly elaborate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that there's some sort of auto conversion between the formats. As `Jersey` implements the `JAX-RS`-standard you can use the annotations provided by the standard.
So for example if you want your method to accept data in XML you could just annotate it with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` and `Jersey` will try to automatically convert the message XML into `POJO`s. I didn't work with XML yet, but I used `JAX-RS` with `JSON` and it worked just fine for `@Consumes` and `@Produces`.
It's possible that you need to annotate your `POJO`s with XML annotations like `@XmlRootElement` to make it work, but in concept the main conversion work is done by the framework and no custom implementations are needed in most cases.

Comment: what if i can not put annotation on few POJO classes does it mean i have to write my own custom MessageBodyReader and MessageBodyWriter to convert xml into POJO and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

That specific section of the documentation provides an example for writing a MessageBodyReader that converts an entity into an xml document.  The excerpt you refer to is explaining that you don't need to write a MessageBodyReader to handle xml because Jersey provides one by default.  They provide the example so you can write a MessageBodyReader to handle conversion of the entity stream into your custom pojo (MyWonky.class).